# Why method should be converted to a property?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a method named Check_Finished() but the visual studio won't allow me to do so. Instead, it prompts me as *potential fix* to convert it into a property. I can't understand why can't we use a method instead of the property here, provided that both have the same purpose and both are gonna return the same thing.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LKoN.png)

**This(below) is the code I want to use.**

```
public bool Check_Finished()
    {
        if(started && !running)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

**This is the one visual studio prompts me to convert to:**

```
public bool Check_Finished
    {
        get
        {
            if (started && !running)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

which still isn't working. Here this happens:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FIEv.png)

I can do the following and it works but I wanted to try a different approach just to understand things more.

```
public bool Finished
    {
        get { return started && !running; }
    }
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the function except that it does not return a value in all cases. You need a `return false;` at the end after the `if` block. Visual Studio and other refactoring tools may have plenty of suggestions about what they think the best way to write code is, but they are only suggestions that you are free to ignore.

Comment: For something simple, I would favor the property, which I would rename as IsFinished.  `public bool IsFinished => started && !running;`

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use a method, but all code paths need to return a value. What if the condition (if-statement) doesn't pass? What should be returned? You don't specify it, leading to a case where no return value is given, which causes the compiler error.

But in general, for such a case, you should prefer using a property, as it represents data and no special calculations have to be done in order to return the value (this wording is not necessarily the rule, but it is easy to "remember" what to use with this mnemonic, though you will get a feeling for that with more experience). Take a look at the [MSDN guideline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms229054(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for using properties or methods:

> In general, methods represent actions and properties represent data. Properties are meant to be used like fields, meaning that properties should not be computationally complex or produce side effects. When it does not violate the following guidelines, consider using a property, rather than a method, because less experienced developers find properties easier to use.